# How do I disable a HDD/Pen drive LED blinking?

Tags: hardware, usb-drive, external-hdd

I want hardware config on ubuntu for pen drive LED blinking.

Answer (score 0):

This is most of the time hardware related and cannot be configured via software, Ubuntu has nothing to do with it.

If you want to disable the LED from your computer case just remove the wire from your motherboard that lights it up, same if we are talking about an external disk case.

From a USB pen there are not a lot of options for that, maybe killing it electronically?